# Uniform continuity.

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

> Check if the mappings
>
> $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto x^2$ and $[0,\infty[:\mathbb{R},x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$
>
> are uniformly continuous.

I was going through some old exams our teacher gave us and this was one of the problems in there.

I have troubles appraoching this. I mean, I know the definition of uniform continuity but I don't know how to apply it to find solutions to explicit problems.

Can anyone show me how to solve this type of things?

Comment: do you know any theorems about uniform continuity, e.g. each function continuos on a closed bounded interval is also uniformly continous there? This will help you with the square root...apart from that, choose some $\varepsilon$ and simply try to find a $\delta$ such that the condition defining continuity is valid. If you note that you can't then you should be suspicious that the function is not uniformly continuous. (More specifically: try $\varepsilon =1,01$ and try to find $\delta$, independent of $x$ such that $|x^2 - (x-1)^2|\le \delta$...)

Comment: @Thomas I can't seem to find $\delta$. I got to: $|2x-1|\leq \delta$. How do I get delta from that and $\epsilon =1,01$?

Comment: Well, for that one you are done -- quite obviously, if only $x>2 (\delta +1)$, the requested inequality is violated. So $x^2$ is not uniformly continous, because you can write down one specific $\varepsilon$ for which the requested condition cannot be fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with $f(x)=x^2$, we proceed as follows:

Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.
Then for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, $\exists$ $\delta \gt 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \lt \epsilon$ whenever $|x-y| \lt \delta$ for any $x,y \in \Bbb R$.

Let $x=a$ and $y=a+\frac \delta2$.
Then we have $|x-y|=|a-(a+\frac \delta2)| \lt \delta$. Hence
$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x^2-y^2|=|a^2-(a+ \frac \delta2)^2| \lt \epsilon$.
$\Rightarrow$ $|a\delta+\frac {\delta^2}{4}| \lt \epsilon$. Hence $|a\delta| \lt \epsilon$ too. $\Rightarrow$ $|a| \lt \frac {\epsilon}{\delta}$ $\forall a \in \Bbb R$. This is impossible! Hence $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.

For $g:[0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ with $g(x)=\sqrt x$, we proceed as follows:

Consider the interval $[0,2]$. Then this interval is closed and bounded and hence from Heine-Borel theorem it is compact in $\Bbb R$. Also since $g$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ it is continuous on $[0,2]$ too. So we get that $g$ is a continuous function on a compact set. Hence $g$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $[0,2]$.

Now consider the interval $[1,\infty)$. Then for $x,y \in [1,\infty)$ we have $|g(x)-g(y)|=|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|=\frac {|x-y|}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y} \lt \frac {|x-y|}{2}$. We can see that $g$ is a Lipschitz function on $[1,\infty)$ with the Lipschitz constant $\frac 12$. Hence $g$ is uniformly continuos on $[1,\infty)$ too!

Combining the two arguments(about the interval $[0,2]$ and the interval $[1,\infty)$), we see that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.